# $wpdb->get_var next var?

Tags: wpdb

This is giving the same views value for each post how would I grab the next var for each post?

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?>

    <?php
    // set the meta_key to the appropriate custom field meta key
    $meta_key = 'views';
    $views = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( 
        "
            SELECT meta_value
            FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
            WHERE meta_key = %s
        ", 
        $meta_key
    ) );
    echo "<p>Total views {$views}</p>";
    ?> 

    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: your query is missing the post id

Answer (score 1):

Instead of querying the database directly you could use the following code instead.

```
printf( '<p>Total views : %s</p>', get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'views', true ) );
```